# Setup each Scalatest "Should" block with specific code

Tags: scalatest

I want to setup each "should" block in my suite with a different input file.
After which, each "in" block will use it's own should block file.

I'm familiar with beforeAll and with beforeEach but they don't help me since beforeAll runs once before all tests and beforeEach runs the same code before each test where I want to run different code for each test.

I tried writing my setup code inside each "should" block but this way all the "should" setup code runs first before the "in" blocks. 
The following is what I tried and also explains what I need:

```
"ParquetFormatParser with input file 1" should {
    setupFile1()
    "do something 1" in {
        useFile1()
    }
    "do something 2" in {
        useFile1()
    }   }

"ParquetFormatParser with input file 2" should {

    setupFile2()
    "do something 1" in {
        useFile2()
    }
    "do something 2" in {
        useFile2()
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you base on your comment about `beforeEach` but you can use fixtures for setting up the files.  This way, files are only setup when needed and tests are independent of each other.

```
trait FileOneFixture {
  // setup file here
}

"ParquetFormatParser with input file 1" should {
   "do something 1" in new FileOneFixture {
     useFile1()
   }
   "do something 2" in new FileOneFixture {
     useFile1()
   }
}
```